# Rust impl Trait as function return type

Tags: rust

I have the following function in which `Command` is a trait

```
pub fn parse_arguments(matches: ArgMatches) -> Result<impl Command, &'static str>
```

Inside the function body, I want to return different implementations of Command depending on the arguments
like

```
match args.subcommand() {
    ("init", Some(args)) => {
        Ok(Init::new(args))
    }
    ("btc", Some(args)) => {
        Ok(ImportBtc::new(args))
    },
    ("grin", Some(args)) => {
        Ok(ImportGrin::new(args))
    },
    _ => Err ("Invalid subcommand supplied")
}
```

Compilation will fail with an error:

```
expected struct `commands::cmd_types::Init`, found struct `commands::cmd_types::ImportBtc`
```

and similar for the `ImportGrin` return line.

Have I misunderstood how `impl Trait` works?

Comment: Here are some "official" examples of `impl Trait`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't quite what `impl Trait` does. `impl Trait` as a return type means "This function will return a single type which implements this trait", whereas you're trying to return multiple types which implement the trait. This is hard for the compiler because it needs to know how big the type being returned is, and different types have different sizes.

Some options:

1. Box the return values, because a `Box` always has the same size
2. Define an `enum` which has a variant per return type, wrap your return values in the `enum`, and implement the trait for the `enum`.
3. Use https://crates.io/crates/auto_enums which automates the enum creation described in 2.

Comment: I would add that, for this kind of usage, the idiomatic option would definitely be #1. The return type can remain `impl Trait`, though, so that if you change your mind and switch to another strategy down the line, the callers won't notice the change.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd describe any as more or less idiomatic - they have different trade-offs.

Boxing will require a heap allocation, and add runtime vtable-lookup overhead.

Using an enum may waste stack space (e.g. if the variants have different sizes), and adds a match lookup at runtime.

But I agree that keeping the `impl Trait` return type is a good thing to do either way!

Comment: I agree with what you said - I described it as idiomatic because that's what I'd expect in a typical rust code base _for this kind of usage_. The reason is that it is hard to imagine that the cost of boxing and vtable indirection would matter for argument parsing. Using an enum (with or without the `auto_enums` crate) adds complexity for no good reason.