# How do I return an iterator of arbitrary type from a trait function?

Tags: generics, rust

I have the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f17b212038203b2ab08344ca28e8ba8c) where I would like to implement a trait that returns an iterator:

```
trait MyTrait<V> {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = V>;
    fn produce_iter(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}

struct MyStruct<V> {
    values: Vec<V>,
}

impl<V> MyTrait<V> for MyStruct<V>
where
    V: Clone,
{
    type Iter = std::vec::IntoIter<V>;

    fn produce_iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.values.clone().into_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        values: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };

    s.produce_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{:?}", v));
}
```

However if I want my implementation of `fn produce_iter(&self)` to be [more complicated](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a304b52aa95d2d6a09064a9c64de19ab) such as

```
fn produce_iter(&mut self) -> Self::Iter {
    self.values
        .clone()
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|v| vec![v, v].into_iter())
        .into_iter()
}
```

instead of

```
fn produce_iter(&mut self) -> Self::Iter {
    self.values.clone().into_iter()
}
```

I run into `error[E0308]: mismatched types` issues trying to figure out what `type Iter = std::vec::IntoIter<V>;` should be instead.

Is there a way of 'generifying' that error away so `fn produce_iter(&self)` can produce arbitrarily complex iterators without having to worry about what I set for `type Iter`? Maybe I should be looking at the problem from a different angle?

Comment: If not for the associated type, you could use [`impl` return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413750/rust-impl-trait-as-function-return-type) to hide away the complexity. But since the associated type is there, I don't know of a way around it in that case.

Comment: Nitpicks: Instead of `vec!` you can use an array, and prefer `iter().cloned()` to `.clone().into_iter()` when the value is `Vec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to be generic over a return value in stable Rust, the return value is always either a concrete type or determined base on input type. The return type must be fully spelled out.

However, there is a way to return multiple types through trait object. Read more about trait object from [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Instead of returning a concrete type from `produce_iter`, return a `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = V>>` trait object.

```rust
trait MyTrait<V> {
    fn produce_iter(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = V>>;
}

struct MyStruct<V> {
    values: Vec<V>,
}

impl<V> MyTrait<V> for MyStruct<V>
where
    V: Clone + 'static,
{
    fn produce_iter(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = V>> {
    Box::new(
        self.values
            .clone()
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(|v| vec![v.clone(), v].into_iter())
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        values: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };

    s.produce_iter().for_each(|v| println!("{:?}", v));
}
```

But beware that trait objects are slower than concrete types, becuase trait objects use dynamic dispatch at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

On nightly you can use [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063):

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

impl<V> MyTrait<V> for MyStruct<V>
where
    V: Clone + std::ops::Mul,
{
    type Iter = impl Iterator<Item = V>;

    fn produce_iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.values
            .clone()
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(|v| vec![v, v].into_iter())
            .into_iter()
    }
}
```

On stable you must use `Box<dyn Iterator>`.