# How to correctly return "impl Trait" as generic parameter in rust function?

Tags: rust

I want to return trait implementations like this:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use rand::prelude::*;

trait A {}

struct A1;
struct A2;

impl A for A1 {}
impl A for A2 {}

struct Foo<T: A> {
    _p: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: A> Foo<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            _p: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

fn hello() -> Foo<impl A> { // <-- expects to return an implementation of "A"
    let b: bool = random();
    if b {
        Foo::<A1>::new()
    } else {
        Foo::<A2>::new()
    }
}

fn main() {
    hello();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d179525282fd7b7121a3ee6d6597ddb)

The above codes failed to compile because

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:9
   |
24 | fn hello() -> Foo<impl A> {
   |               ----------- expected `Foo<A1>` because of return type
...
29 |         Foo::<A2>::new()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Foo<A1>`, found `Foo<A2>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Foo<A1>`
              found struct `Foo<A2>`
```

Is it possible to make the codes work?

PS1: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413750/rust-impl-trait-as-function-return-type), it suggests boxing the return value. But what to box here?

PS2: I can't return `Box<dyn A>`, because in the actual situation, the trait A has associate types, which can't be specified upfront.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=466f3dd7212ecc624d1e5f032fe62dd2